# Email charset. HTML emails. PHP mail

Tags: php

I ve problem with php charset in body message. Mail contains characters: Å¾Å™Ã½Å¾Å¡Å¾Ã½Ä›Ã½Ã¡Å¾Ã½Ã­Ã½Å¾Ã

My contact.php

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "mail@gmail.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = 'Message';
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];



  //send email

  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "OK";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form

  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Please, can you help me with UTF8 enconding? Thank you so much

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - the title of your question should be a question, not a list of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try use php mailer class and tell it:

```
$mail->CharSet='UTF-8';

$mail->Subject=utf8_encode("=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode('you utf8 string')."?=");
```

Or, if you don't want to use php mailer class, you can always use a translate function:

```
str_replace(
    array(,'¡','¿','á','é','í','ñ','ó','ú','Á','É','Í','Ñ','Ó','Ú'),
    array('&#161;','&#191;','&#225;','&#233;','&#237;','&#241;','&#243;','&#250;','&#193;','&#201;','&#205;','&#209;','&#211;','&#218;'),
    $yourstring
);
```

My example is for a Latin (Spanish) alphabet,

Comment: I havent php mailer. where to add str_replace(array(,'¡','¿','á','é','í','ñ','ó','ú','Á','É','Í','Ñ','Ó','Ú'),array('¡','¿','á','é','í','ñ','ó','ú','Á','É','Í','Ñ','Ó','Ú'),$yourstring);

Answer (score 0):

try to use this on form to force utf-8 encoding

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: hmm didnt help me. same problem, email text look like: Ä›Å¡ÄÅ™Å¾Ã½Ã¡Ã­Ã© ( i need - ě, č, ř, ž, ý, á)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add meta in header of your script page ?
Like following :

`<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>`

Comment: what u mean script page? I added meta to contact.php and to form.php. but same problem, thx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using `UTF8` everywhere!

**php **header()****

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

and

**`html meta` tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: @user3719545 which webserver you are using?